# PHP Code Hinting Dynamically Created Classes

Tags: php, ide

I'm writing an autoloader but can't seem to get code hinting working on PHPStorm.

Here is the autoloader

```
function __autoloader()
{
    $arr = array(
        'class1',
        'class2',
        'class3',
    );

    foreach ($arr as $class)
    {
        require_once($class . '.php');
    }
}

$obj = new class1();
$obj->????
```

Assuming that each class is completely different, what is the best way to get code hinting with the above code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With autoloaded classes, I do not think PHPstorm has the capability to do codehinting at the moment.

[Check out more at this discussion](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-381)