# PHP IDE hint for classes instantiated by __call() function

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, ide, type-hinting, code-snippets

I am using VSCode and PHP 8.1+. In standard way, we can get hints when we type `$myClass->???` and we will get a list of functions within the class.

However, recently I have a class that could dynamically instantiate other class within the `$myClass`. I would like to get also the hints of the dynamically instantiate classes. For example `$myClass->otherClass()->??` could get a lists of functions of `OtherClass.php`. Is there anywhere I could specify the rules to let IDE knows?

The following is a sample condition

```
class myClass{
  public $helpers = [];
  public function __call($helper, $args)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($helper, $this->helpers)){
            return $this->helpers[$helper];
        }
        
        $class = 'App\Services\Helpers\\' . ucfirst(str($helper)->camel()) . "Helper";
        if (class_exists($class)) {
            $this->helpers[$helper] = new $class($this, ...$args);
            return $this->helpers[$helper];
        }

        throw new \RuntimeException("Class {$class} does not exist");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$myClass = new myClass;
$myClass->test()->??? //showing hints of App\Services\Helpers\TestHelper class
```

I have read this thread but seem cannot be solved.
[PHP Code Hinting Dynamically Created Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227816/php-code-hinting-dynamically-created-classes)

**Update**

This is a closer one I can get. But it still require me to add all possible classes and methods.

```
/**
 * @method \App\Services\Helpers\TestHelper test()
 * @method \App\Services\Helpers\Test2Helper test2()
 * ....
 */
class myClass{
  public $helpers = [];
  public function __call($helper, $args)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($helper, $this->helpers)){
            return $this->helpers[$helper];
        }
        
        $class = 'App\Services\Helpers\\' . ucfirst(str($helper)->camel()) . "Helper";
        if (class_exists($class)) {
            $this->helpers[$helper] = new $class($this, ...$args);
            return $this->helpers[$helper];
        }

        throw new \RuntimeException("Class {$class} does not exist");
    }
}
```